# Use typescript to extend the generic keys of a generic object input

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I have the following typescript code:

```
type StrictPropertyCheck<T, TExpected> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof TExpected> extends never ? Record<string, unknown> : 'TypeWithStrictPropertyCheck';

export const check = <
    T1 extends Record<string, string | string[]>,
    T2 extends T1 & StrictPropertyCheck<T2, T1>,
  >(arg: {
    myKey: [T1, ...T2[]]
  }): {
    myKey: T1[]
  } => {
  return arg
}

export const template = check({
  myKey: [{
    a: '',
    b: [''],
    c: ['', '']
  }, {
    a: '',
    b: [''],
    c: ['', '']
  }]
})
```

The `check` function checks that all the objects in the array `myKey` has the same keys and key types for each index.

How can I instead of explicitly typing `myKey` in the function `arg` input, accept any number of keys with any given name, and still have the same check performed for each array related to the individual key?

In short; I would like `arg` to accept any key instead of an explicit one.

EDIT:

The array for each `arg`-key should consist of objects, where the key-names in every object is exactly the same as the key-names in the first object in the array. Additionally, the key-type of each object-key in every object, must match the key-type of the corresponding key-name in the first object. The key-types in each object can either be `string[]` or `string`.

(this is what the check function does, just not for any `arg`-key)

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WK8Ygw) meet your needs?  If it works for your use cases I'll write up an answer; if not, please edit your question to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately no. The type of each key is not constrained to be the same in each object index with that solution.

Comment: For instance this example [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZTAJwJYDsDmAhAhpuAXjgCUYBjAe2QBMAeAZxQ0wBo4m0s4AfOZGLhqV0AGwgdmWANoBdAHwBuUJFiIpOfAEFkyXBOIChI8XGlIumtnAB0diyzyY5s5eGjwH5MAGEAFhQA1ggArgBGDDAAjiEw6GAACsiUsMhgqDAMdAAqcDAAHmBxNAzqlk46ehDyRHAA3qBwTWYAknAYcIEwEJQAZnDZsgBc9WYA0u3ond19A9ItssNwEwVF6CXTPf3Z0gAMsnAA-HML0mMHIwDk2R4A6qhgfl6JyamQ-kGXcAC+P24FUGoYDgVHQTBBAXIgVqOTyhWKpTq40mm1mgxGDiwFV0+jgADIyqhvB8oaEItFYvEkikYGkMlkducat95AAKRrNXDITAjbIASiINQaIGa-BgYBCyCmXMwoG+oFA5EhgVZwtFAFsIGNuiNpGrRZzdZdLrJWBymt92PqDXBcFdLmaRc1vrI5XzQEA).

Comment: So then does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Nn4rqW) work?  I really do recommend you [edit] the example code your question to include the use cases you care about instead of relying on a combination of verbal descriptions and code in comments.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It should not be possible to omit keys present in the first.

Comment: See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZTAJwJYDsDmAhAhpuAXjgCUYBjAe2QBMAeAZxQ0wBo4m0s4AfOZGLhqV0AGwgdmWANoBdAHwBuUJFiIpOfAEFkyXBOIChI8XGlIumtnAB0diyzyY5s5eGjwH5MAGEAFhQA1ggArgBGDDAAjiEw6GAACsiUsMhgqDAMdAAqcDAAHmBxNAzqlk46ehDyRHAA3qBwTWYAknAYcIEwEJQAZnDZsgBc9WYA0u3ond19A9ItssNwEwVF6CXTPf3Z0gAMsnAA-HP70mMHIwDk2R4A6qhgfl6JyamQ-kGXcAC+P24FUGoYDgVHQTBBAXIgVqOTyhWKpTq40mm1mgxGDiwFV0+jgADIyqhvB8oaEItFYvEkikYGkMlkducat95AAKRrNXDITAjbIASiINQaIGa-BgYBCyCmXMwoG+oFA5EhgVZwtFAFsIGNuiNpGrRZzdZdLrJWByDXAwldLuafux9RbcEaTbbvrI5XzQEA).

Comment: Then how about [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Wkj6Pm)?  Also, please, I'm begging you, put your test cases in the code in the question.  That is: think of your use cases ahead of time, and put them in the question as code so that I can work on the solution all at once instead of having to play [whack-a-mole](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whack-a-mole#Noun) in the comments.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you @jcalz:) I will try to be more specific in the future! I will approve that as the correct answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can take is to turn your `T1` and `T2` type parameters into object types where for each property key `K in keyof T1`, the property values `T1[K]` and `T2[K]` are like your old `T1` and `T2` values.  That yields this code:

```
export const check = <
    T1 extends { [K in keyof T1]: Record<string, string | string[]> },
    T2 extends { [K in keyof T1]: T1[K] & StrictPropertyCheck<T2[K], T1[K]> },
    >(arg: { [K in keyof T1]: [T1[K], ...T2[K][]] }) => arg;
```

It works, I think:

```
check({
    myKey: [{
        a: '',
        b: [''],
        c: ['', ''],
    }, {
        a: '',
        b: [''],
        c: ['', ''],
    }]
}); // okay

check({
    myKey: [{  /* error!     
    ~~~~~ <--  Types of property 'a' are incompatible. */
        a: [''],
    }, {
        a: '',
    }]
})

check({
    myKey: [{ /* error!
    ~~~~~ <-- Property 'd' does not exist on type... */
        a: '',
        b: [''],
        c: ['', ''],
    }, {
        a: '',
        b: [''],
        c: ['', ''],
        d: [""]
    }]
})

check({
    myKey: [{ /* error!
    ~~~~~ <-- Property 'b' is missing in type... */
        a: [''],
        b: ''
    }, {
        a: ['']
    }]
})
```

The only problem I have with it is that the errors appear in a slightly weird place.  Still, this is more or less a direct extension of your version.

---

Another approach is to step back and have `arg` be of a single type parameter type `T`, and then come up with constraints that walk through the properties of `T` and make sure that they conform to your rules.  This is a little easier for the compiler to infer, since you're just asking for `T` given a value of type `T`, instead of `T1` and `T2` given a value of type `{[K in keyof T1]: [T1[K], ...T2[K][]] }`.  Here it is:

```
// give names to types used more than once
type StringBag = Record<string, string | readonly string[]>;
type StringBagArray = readonly [StringBag, ...StringBag[]];

    
type StrictCheckSubsequentProperties<T extends StringBagArray> = {
    [I in keyof T]: T[0] & {
        [K in keyof T[I]]: K extends keyof T[0] ? T[I][K] : 'TypeWithStrictPropertyCheck'
    }
};

export const check = <T extends { [K in keyof T]:
    StringBagArray & StrictCheckSubsequentProperties<T[K]>
}>(arg: T) => arg;
```

This works by checking that each property in `arg` is a `StringBagArray` (an array of objects whose properties are `string` or `string[]`) and that all elements of that array are assignable to the type of the first element, and that any extra keys are of type `'TypeWithStrictPropertyCheck'` (we could also have written `never` or something else there).

And it also works:

```
check({
    myKey: [{
        a: '',
        b: [''],
        c: ['', ''],
    }, {
        a: '',
        b: [''],
        c: ['', ''],
    }]
}) // okay

check({
    myKey: [{
        a: [''],
    }, {
        a: '', /* error!
        ~ <-- Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]' */
    }]
})


check({
    myKey: [{
        a: '',
        b: [''],
        c: ['', ''],
    }, {
        a: '',
        b: [''],
        c: ['', ''],
        d: [""] /* error!
        ~ <-- string[] is not assignable to "TypeWithStrictPropertyCheck" */
    }]
})

check({
    myKey: [{
        a: [''],
        b: ''
    }, {  // error!
        a: ['']
    }] /*
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--  Property 'b' is missing in type...
    */
})
```

I prefer the error locations in this version, which tend to be more localized to the place where the problem is.  But it's ultimately up to you to decide which version, if any, meets your needs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9jZBvAsAKCUKQBcBPTJAZWICcBLeYgBRowhrIGEALCeAawA8AFQA0SYQFEAHpkYQAJgD4kAXiQz4AGwCuCiIP4RSaAGYTxRk+amy+xRSojSHwBVCTAIAN3ZIA-EgASnxoNAqCULR0wADm4jrA-MBoAO7AKgBcSADkwuQQAOp0xNzU9IwsbBykPHz8OQDc+PhESM4wYcRI8GjAUT28AmpIgq1tRMIAjO0uEG4eWEgA2gDSSDFIVmYSUwC62SG94ZHRceJR9HFIAD5IlzGxy3sqAL6i4xMSAEyzru5IJZrDbALbGHbTA67NZ7JAAMio0UqrEwNTqAhE3xh4mmMLeHwIXyQSgAFCAaLFskD1pttjZ9tllrjVntxAA6DnCLEs56w14ASjUKnJsWaeE+g3qJNwhK+YFIq2MjJlRImIGyORyBNVbQARozNayJar4AatbkckbZRN3oDjUT1RbtTrCPqVobnS7Te7zR77YRXnsJQLGkgAPRhpBofggUgta3wIb8aX+pDyxWkZWEMMAKnaNFYNAAhBNUwA-CsV0YAWmrhHymA8OxgKPYZFyIBySHJyBivTAcGIdF1WggbKQObDqbajuWfutbVtKpd3Y1WtTgeD-PjbUTUuXcoVSpWS1z+cLRfLlbLNbrVVR7ZyCi7CjQ0E8aG6zjoAz6JAKHLjpO05EI6mqejqbpzpaEEmma4jzqqS4gYQYHrguRJQYhK7etBCEwShSAKIyABEJFBhhAYUYu27igmSYppRaZHpmJ7hnm7AXlela3kg95tqQuS6l2P5pj+UCPCC-6YIBE5TkxM5mlaK5IG6mobuIB46rOhobtRRACvG+CvEZeBkBQ5SPAAQiAsQjEcYQRA85z3Gcdl3DQEAgK+wBaIJzlPC8YrmcgllxDZsQAIIFrGIyed5fR+SsYWxBF7IcilEW8mK+AhYiFTEOi-CUDoupQBAACOOjzMwrYcHQ0AiH88wApltnRTQsYqOoWnLAAklJdISFCwjLAADLCCJaW0wK0uCNj9XsULrM4-weENo0TQEEiLTCSAag2RQlGUSK1dUXBJjkwbGWKHRdD0fQDHuwzqE1q0tYsKw0qCG0HBKbVRTFgkIpZjBFSVZWVdVwBnQ+DVQCIeLGaSIrZMIgqqMKFI5Xgz3Jlp6bHss02gWusFEFhBFMbh4EWspBmaamaHk66Sksz08F0xBm54AK4aRtGsbxnjjFtITrHE0zbPBozTHM+x55hJeTE3oItYSAUuQBSJHgpN0IBQBJsSgCOyDEGg0nIDkAXPF2wHWjzhl0fgIsEyxypS06qaU-TXw076VOLrLqrM970vU5z2FfMRKxkbCZ6cUr5a8TbsKiXr3aG3QxsgKbJAWyRh3FKUoOwwJRUkXJwYUU7LsMW7GYe3L4eqmpV0O5p2aRonxae9B+lUex+DXiPo-XrxfF1Y+wkbB4YDiZJmwhYBEr207QA)